# Why gdb is bind to fixed version of autoconf?

Tags: linux, build, gdb, autoconf, autotools

**Edit 1**: I am trying to build gdb from source.

Why can't I use autoconf 2.65 instead of 2.64? It is confusing:(

```
 /var/lib/gforge/chroot/home/users/mirror/ins/ins-autoconf/bin/autoreconf -iv
autoreconf: Entering directory `.'
autoreconf: configure.ac: not using Gettext
autoreconf: running: aclocal
configure.ac:33: error: Please use exactly Autoconf 2.64 instead of 2.65.
config/override.m4:104: _GCC_AUTOCONF_VERSION_CHECK is expanded from...
configure.ac:33: the top level
autom4te: /usr/bin/m4 failed with exit status: 1
aclocal: /var/lib/gforge/chroot/home/users/mirror/ins/ins-autoconf/bin/autom4te failed with exit status: 1
autoreconf: aclocal failed with exit status: 1
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not specific to `gdb`, an explanation (along with possible solutions) is [here](http://gcc.gnu.org/ml/gcc-help/2011-01/msg00248.html).